# Get Arcgis java script library local

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I develop page using arcgis-js api
and call library

```
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/"></script>
```

Can i get this library local with out connect to internet

regards..

Comment: Unfortunately I have to request to close your question because it **lacks the minimum information required** to be answered. Sir, you could have explained what have you tried before. And you have not explained the exact error evidence

Answer (score 0):

You likely have firewalling issues that prevent your client from downloading external assets. Very common in most industries.

You can grab a copy of the file by opening the script URL from your browser, copy the contents into the web application, edit the script tag in order to reference a global script, and then try to run

You **may** encounter a pitfall. Should a Javascript code dynamically create a `<script>` element to add subsequent modules, you will have to perform multiple attempts. Try, fail, repeat.

Example

You have downloaded the script into your webapp's `/assets/esri.js`. Your code becomes

```
<script src="assets/esri.js"></script>
```

Comment: i try this befor but not success

Answer (score 0):

yeah, but, you must have an developer account to download arcgis api for js.  Once you get the library, you must open init.js file.. 
edit `init.js`, search for hostname word, and replace it for localhost or current ip:

[setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSVmc.png)

now, import `init.js` and themes from dojo:

[importing to html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynoIH.png)

now, you can use the library...